# Style trigger from parent control

Tags: xaml, datatrigger, devexpress-wpf

Is it possible to use a style trigger from another control?

I have `Border` control which lives in the indicator part of each row of a grid (the indicator is the part on the very left with the little arrow). I want to set the background depending if the row is selected. So I created a style:

```
<controls:SelectionConverter x:Key="SelectionConverter" />
<Style x:Key="SelectionStyle" TargetType="Border">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SelectionConverter}}"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <!-- here I want to have a trigger which reacts on a property of the grid control -->
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The border control then will use the style (in fact there are 3 border controls).

The `SelectionConverter` will return the correct color depending on the row (that works fine).

The problem is that the background is not updated when I select a different cell (which does make sense, because there is no trigger when to update it).

Is it possible to setup a trigger of the parent control?

Something alone the line

```
<Trigger Property="ParentControl.SelectionHasChanged" Value="True"></Trigger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `ElementName` in your `Binding` to achieve this. For example, the following binds to the `IsEnabled` property of a `Grid` and sets the `Background` property of the `Border` to red when this is `true`:

```
<Grid x:Name"main_grid">
    ...
    <controls:SelectionConverter x:Key="SelectionConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="SelectionStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SelectionConverter}}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=main_grid}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for!

Comment: In addition, can I also put the data trigger to an event of the grid somehow? As far as I get I can only assign animations to event trigger!?

Comment: There is an example of including an animation within a `DataTrigger` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80388/wpf-data-triggers-and-story-boards. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's not just what I need. I want to have a trigger which hooks on an event, but where I'm able to set for example a property on the grid

Comment: Could you give more specifics on the structure and what you need to happen (maybe add it into your question if it's a lot of info)? Also, are you using an MVVM/data binding approach?