# WPF Animate different control after first animation is over

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-animation

I'm animating text in StatusBarItem (from right to left and then Opacity two times). 
When this animation finishes It would like to show a button which is in a different StatusBarItem and is set to **Visibility.Hidden** by default.
How can I do this in XAML?

My XAML - error is "**A storyboard tree in a Style cannot specify a TargetName**":

```
   <StatusBarItem x:Name="Stat_info" DockPanel.Dock="Right" FontStyle="Italic" Height="23" Foreground="#FFB41414" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Hidden">

                <StatusBarItem.Style>

                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StatusBarItem}">

                        <Style.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="flashAnimate">
                                <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content" >
                                    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="T" KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
                                    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Te" KeyTime="0:0:0.6" />
                                    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Tes" KeyTime="0:0:0.9" />
                                    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Test" KeyTime="0:0:1.2" />
                                 </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" BeginTime="0:0:1.4" Duration="0:0:2.0" RepeatBehavior="0:0:5.4" />

                                <!--This is a button that should be set to visible-->
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Btn_info" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                            </Storyboard>

                        </Style.Resources>

                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName= Stat_info, Path= IsVisible}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Name="flash" Storyboard="{StaticResource flashAnimate}" />
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="flash"/>
                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>

                    </Style>

                </StatusBarItem.Style>

            </StatusBarItem>
```

EDIT:

I've tried provided answer from link, but I can't get It to work. I tried with & without **TargetName** and just for first animation. Result is no error & no animation :

```
 <Window.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="StatusBarItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type StatusBarItem}">

                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="myAnimation" Storyboard.TargetName="Stat_info">
                                    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content" >
                                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="T" KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
                                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Te" KeyTime="0:0:0.6" />
                                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Tes" KeyTime="0:0:0.9" />
                                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Test" KeyTime="0:0:1.2" />
                                     </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Stat_info" From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" BeginTime="0:0:1.4" Duration="0:0:2.0" RepeatBehavior="0:0:5.4" />

                             </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ElementName= Stat_info, Path= IsVisible}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="beginAnimation"  Storyboard="{StaticResource myAnimation}" />
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard  BeginStoryboardName="beginAnimation" />
                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <!-- Content to be animated goes here -->

        </ControlTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

   <StatusBarItem x:Name="Stat_info" Visibility="Hidden" Template="{StaticResource StatusBarItemControlTemplate1}" >
```

Comment: @CorentinPane, I'm afraid not. Animation is created in StatusBarItem that is not the same as StatusBarItem that should be visible in the end of animation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Data Triggers and Story Boards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80388/wpf-data-triggers-and-story-boards)

Comment: @ΩmegaMan, partially. Answer that Ian provided should work as he stated, but I can't get It to work. I must have done something wrong or It just Isn't possible. However I've allready done a workaround with setting different animations for each control separately, but code looks ugly. I've used a trick where I trigger second animation If 1st StatusBarItem is Visible, and then just adjust BeginTime 
 of animation acccordingly - 15 second later, in this time 1st animation stops. But I'm looking for a nicer solution. Please take a look at my edited question.