# How to Start a storyboard animation from just ViewModel in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I've been trying to achieve a transition between a menu changing to another. I am using WPF .Net 8 and Caliburn Micro for MVVM.

so I have created the storyboard animation in the MainView.xaml with the name MenuChangeStart. In my MainViewModel.cs I have a method, called when the user clicks the home button. now I want to start this animation before changing the menu.

```
 public void ActivateHomeView()
 {
     
     
     CurrentMenuIcon = @"\Resources\home.png";
    
     //the MenuChangeStart animation goes here
     ActivateItemAsync(new HomeViewModel());

    

 }
```

I tried to do this in two ways but I have problems in both.

### Method 01: Calling a method from View's CS

so  initially I tried to use this block of code in my MainViewModel.cs but I found that `FindResource` does not exist in it.

```
//MainViewModel.cs
public void MenuChangeOpen()
 {
     Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("MenuChangeStart") as Storyboard;
     sb.Begin();
 }
```

then i can call this `MenuChangeOpen()` from the  `ActivateHomeView()`

#### Method 2: Calling method in view from ViewModel

I Moved this `MenuChangeOpen()`  method to the MainView.xaml.cs and then call it from the ViewModel but i could not find a way to correctly call it. I used the below-mentioned code but it throws an error saying _view is null.

```
//MainViewModel.cs
 private MainView _view; 
 public MainViewModel(MainView view) => _view = view;

//InHome menu change
public void ActivateHomeView()
{
    
    //the _view seems to be null
    CurrentMenuIcon = @"\Resources\home.png";
    if(_view != null)
    {
        _view.MenuChangeOpen();
    }
    
    ActivateItemAsync(new HomeViewModel());

   

}
```

Comment: Simply don't do it if you want to implement correct MVVM. In MVVM the view model does not deal with user interaction, UI and UI logic. As such the animation of UI object must be handled in the view. You don't have to use XAML, but do it in the view. You can of course use a view model property to trigger an animation e.g. an IsBusy property could trigger an animation that fades in a progress bar. The fact that you have to pass in controls to your view model should ring the alarm.

Comment: MVVM does not mean that the view model is the application and has to do everything. There is also a model and a view. MVVM is about responsibilities and user interaction (UI) and UI logic are precisely defined as a responsibility of the view. The view model is the most boring component in MVVM. It only gets data from the model and presents it to the view. The view gets data for presentation from the view model and also sends data that was modified by the user back to the view model. The actual application is implemented in the model and all UI related belongfs to the view.

Comment: Here you find some options how the view could start animations: [Microsoft Learn: Animation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: I suggest you use a data trigger to start your storyboard. And a bool property to your viewmodel, set that true to start the animation and bind to it in a data trigger. Probably best searching yourself but here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80388/wpf-data-triggers-and-story-boards

Answer (score 0):

use the EventTrigger in XAML along with an EventTriggerBehavior from the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf NuGet package.

```cs
    private RelayCommand _startAnimationCommand;

    public RelayCommand StartAnimationCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _startAnimationCommand ?? (_startAnimationCommand = new RelayCommand(param => StartAnimation()));
        }
    }
```

in xaml: add

```xml
<Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="YourAnimationStoryboard">
            <!-- Define your animation here -->
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Start Animation">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StartAnimationCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
        </Grid>
```